# SQL Server or MYSQL for use with Android?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, json

I am going to be paying for a hosted sql database in the next few days. I will be using it to store data and interact with an Android app. Is there more support for MySQL using phpmyadmin, PHP backend and parsing with JSON and sending htttp posts? Or is there a better (easier/simpler) way to use SQL Server?

Comment: for php I would suggest mysql.. Also, you will have to pay for MSSQL

Comment: Express is free, and hosted wise MSSQL is 4.99 a month and MYSQL is 5.99 a month. Also, I didn't know if PHP is my only option.

Comment: To me, the better(easier/simplery) way is mysql phpmyadmin.

Comment: Just to be clear, the SQL database will not be running on the Android device itself, right?  If the database is running on a server somewhere and your app is just accessing it, I'd use whatever database you are most comfortable with.  Although, with PHP, I'd tend to agreed with the chat and go MySQL.

Comment: Correct, NO INTERNAL APP DATABASE. If it was a simple small one that didnt have to rely on others input ie (area codes/alch content of beers)  SQLLite would be fine and its all naitively supported. I will have an external server that multiple people will input to (ie.Names, etc)

Comment: android got nothing to do with your question. removing "android" and "java" tags. You are talking about just back-end.

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD If your host is charging more for MySQL than MSSQL, that's a little odd.

Comment: Those were just general quotes I found online. I went with mysql for 3.95/mo. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Android device is sending json http traffic to the service, it doesn't matter which backend database you choose with respect to "Android"

It's more of a question about the type of data you're storing and your comfort with those systems.  If you have a proper interface, you can also swap it out seemlessly without affecting the devices.

The real question is whether you do sql (atomic transactions/relational storage etc...) or a "no sql" database (eventually consistent - hadoop, mongodb, couchdb, S3).  Don't forget that hybrid is a valid option depending on your data needs.

That comparison and analysis on your data is probably beyond the scope of an S.O. post but there's plenty of content available discussing the pros and cons of each.

One other piece of advice - if you pay for data storage and you pay for some front end servers, try to get them in the same geolocation or same data center if possible.  For that reason, sometimes it's best to get both from the same cloud vendor (Azure, Amazon, etc...) - not to mention convenient billing.